# converting between float <-> int in javascript

Tags: javascript, ieee-754

I have a javascript program (running in jsdb which uses Mozilla Spidermonkey 1.8, not in a browser) that I need to convert float and doubles to/from the appropriate number of bytes of their IEEE representations. Java has [Float.floatToIntBits()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToIntBits%28float%29) and [Float.intBitsToFloat()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat%28int%29) and similar methods for Double.

Is there a way to compute these functions in Javascript? (and yes, I know that all javascript numbers are essentially of type double)

I guess I could follow the algorithms in the javadoc for [Double.longBitsToDouble()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longBitsToDouble%28long%29) and [Float.intBitsToFloat()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat%28int%29) but that only covers one direction, and I need both.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript float from/to bits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003493/javascript-float-from-to-bits)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript float from/to bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003493/javascript-float-from-to-bits)

Answer (score 4):

[javascript float from/to bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003493/javascript-float-from-to-bits)

From the answer: [IEEE-754 Floating-Point Conversion](http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/Decimal.html)

Comment: Just took a look at the Javascript in the babbage.cs.qc.edu site -- It may produce correct answers, and may work well on the online calculator, but it's horribly written & not suitable for reuse in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

As i know, javascript doesn't have such native methods.

Here is some sort of things, you want to have. Please examine the source code: http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/IEEE-754hex32.html