# Converting two Uint32Array values to Javascript number

Tags: javascript, types, numbers

I found a code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14379836/1691517) that converts Javascript number to inner IEEE representation as two Uint32 values:

```
function DoubleToIEEE(f)
{
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(8);
  (new Float64Array(buf))[0] = f;
  return [ (new Uint32Array(buf))[0] ,(new Uint32Array(buf))[1] ];
}
```

How to convert the returned value back to Javascript number? This way:

```
var number = -10.3245535;
var ieee = DoubleToIEEE(number)
var number_again = IEEEtoDouble(ieee);
// number and number_again should be the same (if ever possible)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read/Write bytes of float in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414077/read-write-bytes-of-float-in-js)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That code is ugly as hell. Use

```
function DoubleToIEEE(f) {
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(8);
  var float = new Float64Array(buf);
  var uint = new Uint32Array(buf);
  float[0] = f;
  return uint;
}
```

If you want an actual `Array` instead of a `Uint32Array` (shouldn't make a difference in the most cases), add an [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) call. You can also reduce this to a oneliner by passing the value to the `Float64Array` constructor:

```
function DoubleToIEEE(f) {
  // use either
  return new Uint32Array(Float64Array.of(f).buffer);
  return Array.from(new Uint32Array(Float64Array.of(f).buffer));
  return Array.from(new Uint32Array((new Float64Array([f])).buffer));
}
```

The inverse would just write the inputs into the `uint` slots and return the `float[0]` value:

```
function IEEEToDouble(is) {
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(8);
  var float = new Float64Array(buf);
  var uint = new Uint32Array(buf);
  uint[0] = is[0];
  uint[1] = is[1];
  return float[0];
}
```

which can be shortened to

```
function IEEEToDouble(is) {
  return (new Float64Array(Uint32Array.from(is).buffer))[0];
}
```

Comment: Could you kindly explain to us dummies why the code is ugly?

Comment: @TimoKähkönen The assignment to the throwaway-typedarray on the left hand side is confusing, it's better to write it out explicitly with a variable. And the two `Uint32Array`s where one would suffice seem inefficient. All that makes it hard to understand the data flow and find the inverse function. And of course, I prefer the single-expression forms :-)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I accepted your answer.

Comment: which version of Javascript/ECMAscript does this require?

Comment: @JasonS ES6, though typed arrays can be polyfilled and were supported in some browsers earlier than ES6 as well IIRC.

Answer (score 8):

I found a possible solution, which seems to work:

```
function IEEEToDouble(f)
{
  var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(8);
  (new Uint32Array(buffer))[0] = f[0];
  (new Uint32Array(buffer))[1] = f[1];
  return new Float64Array(buffer)[0];
}
```

Usage:

```
var a = DoubleToIEEE(-0.1234);
console.log(a); // [0, 3220176896]
var b = IEEEToDouble(a);
console.log(b); // -0.1234
```

Comment: If anyone looking to convert from binary representation string: `const BinaryStringToDouble = (x) => IEEEToDouble([x.substring(32), x.substring(0, 32)].map(p => parseInt(p, 2)));`

Comment: beware of byte order; use DataView