# Can I generate a random float on the whole space?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, random, floating-point, buffer-overflow

I am trying to generate a random number that range from Number.MIN_VALUE to Number.MAX_VALUE, but the following algorithm fails due to buffer overflows (I guess) :

```js
var randFloat = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Number.MAX_VALUE - Number.MIN_VALUE)) + Number.MIN_VALUE
```

*Is there any way to do it ?*

Comment: `crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0]` is about as good as it gets; use division to float it

Comment: What do you mean by "use division to float it" ?

Comment: He means that the function will return a sequence of digits in the form of a whole number. Move the decimal to the left by dividing by a power of 10 to create a floating point number with the desired number of digits to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: Generate random 64 bits, then use the formula on the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format to convert those bits to a number. If you don't want `Inf`s and `NaN`s retry unless the exponent equals to `7ff`.

Comment: Won't doing this stop the random numbers from being uniform or reduce the random space ?? :/

Comment: What exactly do you mean by uniform?

Comment: all numbers from Number.MIN_VALUE to Number.MAX_VALUE (included) have the same chance of being chosen, every time

Comment: Do you know that `MIN_VALUE` is the smallest *positive* number?

Comment: Do you only want to generate integers?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "all numbers"? All real numbers? All integer numbers? All representable floating point numbers?

Comment: All floating point numbers

Comment: Then use @zerkms' approach of generating 64 random bits (or 63 if you only want positive values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do:

```
function IEEEToDouble(f)
{
    return new Float64Array(f.buffer)[0];
}

var array = new Uint32Array(2); // here we allocate a 2 element unsigned 32 bit ints
window.crypto.getRandomValues(array); // here we generate 64 bits of random values
var f = IEEEToDouble(array); // and convert 64 bits to a double precision number
```

This generates a uniformly distributed double precision IEEE754 number. So every possible value in the whole space is equally possible to get with this code, including `NaN`s (it's quite a lot of `NaN`s there actually - `2^53 - 2`) and `Infinity`s.

References:

- The initial implementation of the `IEEEToDouble` function borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/21282715/251311
- [RandomSource.getRandomValues()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/RandomSource/getRandomValues)

Comment: Any way it can be done without window.crypto ? I am using Node.JS and it is not available :/

Comment: @Magix https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback Any random source that qualifies your needs is fine.

Comment: Depends on the definition of "uniform" - every value is equally likely, but their density is skewed heavily towards zero.

Comment: I really wonder why you don't simply take `f.buffer`, instead of creating another buffer and two arrays only to copy the value from the input array.

Comment: (see my answer to the linked question)

Comment: @Bergi no particular reason, I just did not bother checking through the details of implementation. Now improved.