# Is there any way to see a number in it's 64 bit float IEEE754 representation

Tags: javascript, binary, ieee-754

Javascript stores all numbers as double-precision 64-bit format IEEE 754 values according to the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf):

> The Number type has exactly 18437736874454810627 (that is, 2<sup>64</sup>−2<sup>53</sup>+3)
>   values, representing the double-precision 64-bit format IEEE 754
>   values as specified in the IEEE Standard for Binary Floating-Point
>   Arithmetic

Is there any way to see the number in this form in Javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript float from/to bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003493/javascript-float-from-to-bits)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @Pointy's suggestion I've implemented the following function to get a number in it's 64 bit float IEEE754 representation:

```
function to64bitFloat(number) {
    var f = new Float64Array(1);
    f[0] = number;
    var view = new Uint8Array(f.buffer);
    var i, result = "";
    for (i = view.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var bits = view[i].toString(2);
        if (bits.length < 8) {
            bits = new Array(8 - bits.length).fill('0').join("") + bits;
        }
        result += bits;
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(to64bitFloat(12)); // 0100000000101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
console.log(to64bitFloat(-12)); // 1100000000101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use typed arrays to examine the raw bytes of a number. Create a `Float64Array` with one element, and then create a `Uint8Array` with the same buffer. You can then set the first element of the float array to your number, and examine the bytes via the `Uint8Array`. You'll have to do some shifting and combining for the various pieces of the number of course, but it's not hard.

There are no built-in facilities to do things like extract the exponent.

Comment: thanks, I tried the following `var f = new Float64Array(1); f[0] = -12; new Uint8Array(f.buffer).join()` and it returned this `0,0,0,0,0,0,40,192` - I was expecting only zeros and ones, but there are `40` and `192` in it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well the `Uint8Array` will contain 8 8-bit values. If you want to see them as binary, you can use `.toString(2)` on each byte - also, you'll have to go through the array in reverse order, as you can see - the "interesting" bytes are at the end. That `192` is the sign bit and the exponent, and then `40` is the most significant part of the mantissa.

Comment: I see, thanks. I'll try that. _you'll have to go through the array in reverse order,_ - is it becausee of `Little Endian Byte Order` ?

Comment: thanks, now the next question I'll probably ask how to parse from binary IEE 754 float to javascript float :)

Comment: I've implemented the function based on your suggestion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37092416/2545680), take a look please if I got everything correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Basenumber.js](https://github.com/AlexSp3/Basenumber.js) to transform a number into its IEEE754 representation:

```js
let x = Base(326.9);
let y = Base(-326.9);

// specify double precision (64)
let a = x.toIEEE754(64);
let b = y.toIEEE754(64);

console.log(a);
console.log(b);

// You can join them in an unique string this way
console.log(Object.values(a).join(""));
console.log(Object.values(b).join(""));
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/AlexSp3/Basenumber.js@main/BaseNumber.min.js'></script>
```