# How to get the actual bytes of a javascript 64bit float

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, typed-arrays

I have been trying to work out how to use typed array's in JavaScript but something just isn't clicking yet for me. I am not understand how to read/write to the "view" properly.

```
var a = 23453.342;
```

now let's say I want to store this in a Float64Array typed array

```
view[0] = ??? //how do I copy the bytes that represent variable a into here.
```

Also let's say I want to store the integer 123456 that is in JavaScript internally as a 64Bit float:

```
var i = 123456;
```

but I would like to store it as if it was really a 4 byte integer.

```
var buff = new ArrayBuffer(4);
var view = new UInt32Array(buff);

view[0] = ???; //how do i determine and write the 4 bytes that would represent the value of i.
```

Then also in both cases once I am able to write the data there how do I read it back into local variables in JavaScript.

Comment: you can check my [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37092416/2545680) that shows the function that allows you to see all bits, also my [this post](https://medium.com/@maximus.koretskyi/javascripts-number-type-8d59199db1b6#.ilgpvngw9) describes in great detail how these numbers are stored. But it seems your question is about how typed array views work, not `How to get the actual bytes of a javascript 64bit float`

Comment: did you understand how typed array views work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a `TypedArray` of a certain type, say `Int8Array` like this:

```
let my = new Int8Array(1);
```

and assign a value to it, like this:

```
my[0] = 123456;
```

a conversion based [on the this table](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#table-49) is performed. So, for `Int8Array` the method [ToInt8](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toint8) is used with the last steps being:

> ... 
>   Let int8bit be int modulo 2^8.
>   If int8bit ≥ 2^7, return int8bit − 2^8, otherwise return int8bit.

So, if we run these steps

```
Let int8bit be 123456 modulo 2^8 // 64
64 < 2^7 -> return int8bit, which is 64
```

So `64` is what you should expect:

```
console.log(my[0]); // 64
```

If you're interested in the actual bits order, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37088194/is-there-any-way-to-see-a-number-in-its-64-bit-float-ieee754-representation/37092416#37092416) for the algorithm or this article for the [details of floating point](https://medium.com/@maximus.koretskyi/javascripts-number-type-8d59199db1b6#.ilgpvngw9).

Comment: I had seen the table you referenced quite a few times but I had completely overlooked the conversion operation and it being automatically performed when you assign the value. Thank you, that was what was missing in my understanding.

Comment: @axawire, you're welcome. By the amount of upvotes of the other answer I was under impression that I misunderstood your question. Thanks for accepting.

Answer (score 6):

If your value is smaller than the Typed Array unit than just store the value into the array, eg you have *23453.342* and using Float64, then just put it into the array

```
var view = new Float64Array(1);
view[0] = 23453.342;
```

Now if you are wanting to convert a number into its individual bytes,eg a 32bit number and get the 4 bytes that make it, you can use two TypedArray views. Put your value into the higher bit array, and read the bytes from the lower unit array.

```js
//The argument passed to ArrayBuffer constructor 
//is number of Bytes the buffer should be
var buff = new ArrayBuffer(4);
//Since buffer was made for 4 bytes, this view can read/store 1 32bit value
var view = new Uint32Array(buff);
//buffer still has 4 bytes, so this view can read/store 4 8bit values
var view2 = new Uint8Array(buff);

view[0] = 123456;
console.log(view2);
```

If you want to manually get the bytes, or do not have access to a higher unit typed array, than you can use the bit shifting and bitwise AND operators to get the individual bytes

```js
var i = 123456;

var buff = new ArrayBuffer(4);
var view = new Uint32Array(buff);
var view2 = new Uint8Array(buff);

view2[0] = i & 0x000000FF;
view2[1] = (i & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
view2[2] = (i & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
view2[3] = (i & 0xFF000000) >> 24; 

console.log( view2, view[0] );
```

As for getting the values back out, in the case of using the two typed arrays, you just read the array of the target unit. In this case read from the Uint32Array

```js
var buff = new ArrayBuffer(4);
var view = new Uint32Array(buff);
var view2 = new Uint8Array(buff);
view2[0] = 64, view2[1] = 226, view2[2] = 1, view2[3] = 0;
var i = view[0];
console.log(i);
```

Again if you want to use the bit shifting way, you need to shift each byte from the smaller typed array and bitwise OR them together.

```js
var buff = new ArrayBuffer(4);
var view = new Uint8Array(buff);
view[0] = 64, view[1] = 226, view[2] = 1, view[3] = 0;
var i = 0;
i |= view[3] << 24;
i |= view[2] << 16;
i |= view[1] << 8;
i |= view[0];
console.log(i);
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your detailed response. I wish I could accept 2 answers but the other answer completed my understanding.