# What is the difference between javascript double and java double

Tags: javascript, java

I need to sort very small values. These values are come from javascript to java.

There is difference between java value and javascript value

> "9.46633086265214**1**E-30" in javascript

is

> "9.46633086265214**2**E-30" in java

"javascript double" use IEEE 754 (11 exponent bits)
"java double" also use IEEE 754 (11 exponent bits)

I know about 100% precision of 15 decimal point. But I don't need accuracy.. 
I just need completely same value between javascript and java.

What is the cause of my case?

Comment: I think we'll need to see the code that generates these values, on both systems.

Comment: Not only what @markspace said, but also Java may calculate doubles differently than Javascript given that they are two completely unrelated languages

Comment: If you don't need accuracy, then reduce the precision such that you get the same representation on both platforms. The cause of the difference seems immaterial.

Comment: I'd try to convert double to its bit representation and send as long, then convert back, check `longBitsToDouble` in java and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14379836/2864275) for javascript